# Convert Anytype to int xcode using as?

Tags: json, swift

I get this error when a try a login in my app.

Namespace SIGNAL, code 0x5

and in the xcode i get

exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

My JSON object looks like this : {'error':1}

in my code I make a request to a web service , I get back a JSON file and I want to convert one key to a int type.

I have this lines, in the first one I delcare the json constant initializing it with the data of the JSON object.

In the second i try to check the error key to verified if the Web service send me and error. I am trying to parse the error key to a int value so I can compare it. And that line is the one that sends me the error.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject] 
let error:Int = json["error"] as! Int
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: *"Any idea of what is wrong?"* No because you haven't told us what is wrong. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what issues you are having with the code you posted. Include complete error messages and the JSON you are trying to parse. Do not reply in a comment. [Edit] your question.

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Answer (score -3):

Skip the try and use `guard let` or `if let` instead

```
if let json = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject] { 
       if let error: Int = json["error"] as? Int {
       }
}
```

Now you can use breakpoints to check what content you receive from json.

If you know it's an String that you want to convert to an Int, just say

`let error = Int(json["error"]) as? Int`

Comment: You need to use `try?` or catch the error and conditionally cast to dictionary which should be `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: AnyObject]` in Swift 3

Comment: `if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] {`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the try from the copy paste

Comment: You can't simply remove `try` keyword.  `jsonObject(with: data)` method throws